# Spark: how to perform loop fuction to dataframes

Tags: sql, scala, function, apache-spark, dataframe

I have two dataframes as below, I'm trying to search the second df using the foreign key, and then generate a new data frame. I was thinking of doing a `spark.sql("""select history.value as previous_year 1 from df1, history where df1.key=history.key and history.date=add_months($currentdate,-1*12)"""` but then I need to do it multiple times for say 10 `previous_year`s. and join them back together. How can I create a function for this? Many thanks. Quite new here.

```
dataframe one:
   +---+---+-----------+
   |key|val| date      |
   +---+---+-----------+
   |  1|100| 2018-04-16|
   |  2|200| 2018-04-16| 
   +---+---+-----------+
dataframe two : historical data
   +---+---+-----------+
   |key|val| date      |
   +---+---+-----------+
   |  1|10 | 2017-04-16|
   |  1|20 | 2016-04-16| 
   +---+---+-----------+
```

The result I want to generate is

```
   +---+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
   |key|date      | previous_year_1 | previous_year_2 |
   +---+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
   |  1|2018-04-16| 10              | 20              |
   |  2|null      | null            | null            |
   +---+----------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I think right join will work, have you tried ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala sorry I updated my question with the desired output. I tried hard code sql but the problem is I need to repeat the same sql if I want 10 years history as columns. That's why I'm looking for some sort of loop function

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala just basic spark.sql("""select history.value as previous_year 1 from df1, history where df1.key=history.key and history.date=add_months($currentdate,-1*12)""" and I'm don't think it's a good idea to do say 10 of them and join them back together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, the following approach can be applied:

1) Join the two dataframes by `key`.

2) Filter out all the rows where previous dates are not exactly years before reference dates.

3) Calculate the years difference for the row and put the value in a dedicated column.

4) Pivot the DataFrame around the column calculated in the previous step and aggregate on the value of the respective year.

```
private def generateWhereForPreviousYears(nbYears: Int): Column =
  (-1 to -nbYears by -1) // loop on each backwards year value
    .map(yearsBack => 
    /*
      * Each year back count number is transformed in an expression
      * to be included into the WHERE clause.
      * This is equivalent to "history.date=add_months($currentdate,-1*12)"
      * in your comment in the question.
      */
    add_months($"df1.date", 12 * yearsBack) === $"df2.date"
  )
    /*
    The previous .map call produces a sequence of Column expressions,
    we need to concatenate them with "or" in order to obtain
    a single Spark Column reference. .reduce() function is most
    appropriate here.
     */
    .reduce(_ or _) or $"df2.date".isNull // the last "or" is added to include empty lines in the result.

val nbYearsBack = 3

val result = sourceDf1.as("df1")
  .join(sourceDf2.as("df2"), $"df1.key" === $"df2.key", "left")
  .where(generateWhereForPreviousYears(nbYearsBack))
  .withColumn("diff_years", concat(lit("previous_year_"), year($"df1.date") - year($"df2.date")))
  .groupBy($"df1.key", $"df1.date")
  .pivot("diff_years")
  .agg(first($"df2.value"))
  .drop("null") // drop the unwanted extra column with null values
```

The output is:

```
+---+----------+---------------+---------------+
|key|date      |previous_year_1|previous_year_2|
+---+----------+---------------+---------------+
|1  |2018-04-16|10             |20             |
|2  |2018-04-16|null           |null           |
+---+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Many thanks! I do want to keep all the rows in df1. Is there a way to modify the join or do I need to join the result back to df1? Also could you explain a bit more about that map reduce generateWhereForPreviousYears fuction? does that produce n number of where clause? what's reduce( _or_) ?

Answer (score 1):

Let me "read through the lines" and give you a "similar" solution to what you are asking:

```
val df1Pivot = df1.groupBy("key").pivot("date").agg(max("val"))
val df2Pivot = df2.groupBy("key").pivot("date").agg(max("val"))

val result = df1Pivot.join(df2Pivot, Seq("key"), "left")
result.show

+---+----------+----------+----------+                                          
|key|2018-04-16|2016-04-16|2017-04-16|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|       100|        20|        10|
|  2|       200|      null|      null|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Feel free to manipulate the data a bit if you really need to change the column names.

Or even better:

```
df1.union(df2).groupBy("key").pivot("date").agg(max("val")).show

+---+----------+----------+----------+                                          
|key|2016-04-16|2017-04-16|2018-04-16|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|        20|        10|       100|
|  2|      null|      null|       200|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```